# Can i have a second partition with a full system in it, encrypted with FileVault/Truecrypt/Whatever?

Tags: filevault

I would like to have  a second partition in my laptop. The second partition, differently from the first one, should be encrypted at a boot level. It will contain all my work stuff.

Is it possible?

Is it secure?

Comment: If you are worried about security both disks really should be encrypted by the operating system.  I assume your using OS X because of the filevault tag?

Comment: No, i need to decide between osx and linux. Undecided, but i use osx right now in my main workstation so it could win this little race. I don't care about the content of the main partition, it could be compromised for what i care. Anyway, if a virus infects the bios that won't matter at this point.

Comment: The number of malicious files that can infect the BIOS can be counted on a man's hand who is missing fingers. If you are worried about the BIOS you have bigger fish to fry.  Besides with `Secure Boot` on your typical personal computer, and the TPM module on Apple computers, you are more likely to win the lottery then be hit by lighting twice then have your BIOS infected.

Comment: That's a comforting answer. So i suppose that there is no problem in having a second, encrypted partition with a full system in it, right? Thanks.

Comment: Why would that be a problem?  Its a supported feature of both OS X (Filevault) and Windows (Bitlocker).  Truecrypt can extend the feature to other supported systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're proposing, you're planning to have two bootable partitions, one encrypted and one not. I can't speak for TrueCrypt, but that's certainly possible with OS X and FileVault 2. The encrypted OS should also be fully secure, unless you do something that interferes with its security:

- When you start up from the unencrypted volume, you'll be prompted to unlock the encrypted volume (with one of the account passwords from that volume); if you follow the prompt and unlock it, any malware in the insecure OS will have access to your "secure" volume. Solution: just click Cancel. There might be a way to keep it from even prompting you, but I haven't looked into it (see this [MacFixIt article: How to prevent a volume from mounting at boot in OS X](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57507755-263/how-to-prevent-a-volume-from-mounting-at-boot-in-os-x/) for one possible approach).
- When you start up from the encrypted volume, the unencrypted volume will mount automatically. This shouldn't be a big deal, it just means you shouldn't store files on that volume, run software from that volume, etc. If you're worried about it, follow the instructions in that same MacFixIt article to avoid mounting the unencrypted volume.